# Как сделать проверку на поля на unique в update?

Tags: php, laravel

Есть метод `update` и поле `name`.

```html
 'name' => 'nullable|unique:services|min:1',
```

Но я не смогу обновить это поля не меняя ему имя так как такое имя уже есть в базе, можно ли сделать, что бы юник не проверял то которое обновляет ? Или самому доставать из базы и сравнивать и тд ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Валидатор `unique` умеет это делать, это написано в [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-unique):

Вам нужно в правилах на `update` получать `ID` с таблицы `services` и написать валидатор:

```
 'name' => 'nullable|unique:services,name,' . $id . '|min:1',
```

И всё, будет искать совпадения по всем записям кроме указанного ID.

Comment: То, что я и искал ) спасибо. Я написал конечно вручную все, но теперь заменю на этот код ))